# What is a non-delegating constructor in c++

Tags: c++, constructor

can someone let me know `What is a non-delegating constructor` ?

I tried to google it but could not find anything useful

Comment: What did you search for? Because the very first result for non-delegating constructor explains what a delegating constructor is, and you should be able to conclude that a non-delegating constructor is a constructor that isn't a delegating constructor.

Comment: To look at the opposite side, C++11 introduced delegating constructors. http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#delegating-ctor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All it means is that the constructor does not delegate. (Which is the case unless you've made some calls between your constructors).

Constructor delegation is quite common in other and newer languages today, all it means is that the constructor is calling another constructor to prevent code duplication and maintain clean code.

Here is a simple tutorial on constructor delegating:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-5-delegating-constructors/